# C++ template class compile error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, hashtable

I'm implementing a HashTable myself and found the following error:

```
 19 template <class key, class value>
 20 class HashEntry { ... }

 60 template <class key, class value>
 61 class HashTable
 62 {
 63 
 64 private:
 65     size_t _tableSize;
 66     HashEntry<key, value>** _table;
 67 
 68 public:
 69 
 70     HashTable(size_t s)
 71     {
 72         _tableSize = s;
 73         _table = (HashEntry<key, value>**) smalloc(s * sizeof(HashTable<key, value>*));
 74     }
 75 
 76     void addEntry(HashEntry<key, value>(key k, value v))  <---
 77     {
 78 
 79     }
 80 
 ...
 91 };

 93 int main ()
 94 {
 95     HashTable<int, string> t(100);
 96     t.addEntry(HashEntry<int, string>(1, string("a")));    <---

HASH_chaining.cc:96: error: no matching function for call to ‘HashTable<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::addEntry(HashEntry<int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)’
HASH_chaining.cc:76: note: candidates are: void HashTable<key, value>::addEntry(HashEntry<key, value> (*)(key, value)) [with key = int, value = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]
```

At glance, I could't find anything wrong with it. I think it has to do with the way I define the addEntry interface though.

Thanks.

Comment: Change `void addEntry(HashEntry<key, value>(key k, value v))` to `void addEntry(key k, value v)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't extract things in the parameter list (looks like that's what you're trying to do).

Change your `addEntry` function so that its signature is either:

```
void addEntry(HashEntry<key, value> h)
```

or

```
void addEntry(key k, value v)
```

The second one seems cleaner in my opinion, but if you really want the caller to construct the `HashEntry` for some reason, the first one is fine as well.

Comment: I just tried void addEntry(HashEntry<key, value> h) and it works. Once mentioned I doubt why had i put it that way in the first way:(

Comment: Admittedly, the HashEntry class is pretty much not a must other than to make the code cleaner and making move around <key, value> pair easier.

Comment: Well, the two options are fundamentally different in who is meant to construct the pair, that's up to you to decide.